# How do I move my family to my new house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I'm playing Skyrim with Hearthfire and I'm wondering how do I move my family(Wife and Daughter) to my new Manor near Morthal?

Comment: Related: Issue specific to Lakeview Manor (Falkreath) - [How do I move my family to Lakeview Manor?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115096/4797)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Talk to your spouse and children, there will be an option to have them move. The destination must have valid sleeping accommodations to appear as a choice.

Answer (score 10):

You need to have a child's chest and bed for them to be able to move aswell. I have 2 children and it wouldn't let me move them until I had built 2 child's chests